# Adonis.js, Ionic and Cors

Tags: ionic-framework, cors, ionic4, adonis.js

I'm trying to get CORS working on my *adonis.js* backend and ionic front end but I can't get anything working for some reason.

I've added the cors provider to my app.js

```
const providers = [
    '@adonisjs/framework/providers/AppProvider',
    '@adonisjs/auth/providers/AuthProvider',
    '@adonisjs/bodyparser/providers/BodyParserProvider',
    '@adonisjs/lucid/providers/LucidProvider',
    '@adonisjs/cors/providers/CorsProvider',
];
```

Loaded it in *kernel.js*

```
const serverMiddleware = [
    'Adonis/Middleware/Cors',
];

Server
    .registerGlobal(globalMiddleware)
    .registerNamed(namedMiddleware)
    .use(serverMiddleware);
```

and I've set my `origin: true` and no matter what I do, nothing seems to be fixing it. I've even done the following function with origin to try get it to log out the origin, and nothing is being logged out, so it makes me wonder if it's even loading my cors.js config.

```
origin: function (currentOrigin) {
    Logger.info(currentOrigin);
    return currentOrigin === 'mywebsite.com'
},
```

Does anyone have any idea as to how to get it working? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you put error message here

Comment: It just give the standard browser cross-origin error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it wasn't even a cors issue. Once I did some more reading it's due to developing on a `localhost/127.0.0.1` environment, which is considered to send back "secure" requests, and it was trying to reach the API on unsecure local ip (`10.0.0.5`). So due to this, Firefox simply blocks all cross origin requests and why it wasn't even making it to my API to log anything out